# Why does Unity “RegisterInstance” function in Prism Framework cann't return a single instance？

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism

Use the Prism framework, I register a single instance as follows:

```
var mLoginController = Container.Resolve<LoginController>();
Container.RegisterInstance<ILoginController>(mLoginController);
var hashCode1 = mLoginController.GetHashCode();
```

Then I try to get a instance as follows in another thread:

```
var mLoginController = Container.Resolve<LoginController>();
var hashCode2 = mLoginController .GetHashCode();
```

And the hashCode1 is different from hashCode2, so strange.

When I change another way to register the single instance as follows：

```
Container.RegisterType<ILoginController, LoginController>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
mLoginController = Container.Resolve<LoginController>();
var hashCode3 = mLoginController.GetHashCode();
```

The hashCode3 is same as hashCode2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

> Container.RegisterInstance<**ILoginController**>(mLoginController);

and

> var mLoginController = Container.Resolve<**LoginController**>();

You register `ILoginController` and you resolve `LoginController`, so you get two different instances. The singleton instance is only registerd for `ILoginController`, so to retrieve it, you should use

`var mLoginController = Container.Resolve<LoginController>();`

BTW - I wouldn't too much rely on `GetHashCode` to decide whether two instances are the same, it may well be implemented incorrectly. Better use `ReferenceEquals` or use the debugger to assign instance ids.